# A simple exercise about sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Please help me to solve the following exercise:

> Consider a sequence of real numbers $\{t_n\}$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} t_n=0$; if $t\in\mathbb R$ is a number such that for every $n\in\mathbb N$ there is $k_n\in\mathbb R$ with the property 
>   $$k_nt_n\le t\le (k_{n}+1)t_{n}$$
>   then prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}k_nt_n=t$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: squeeze theorem.

Hint: $0 \le t - k_nt_n \le t_n$.